# Is this code thread-safe with C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have read articles about double-check which may not be safe with C++ on arbitrary CPU. I am not quite sure whether my codes are absolutely safe or not.
Class Database represents database file, and the connection is dynamically created when needed. Database::GetConnection may be called from different threads simultaneously. If the code is not absolutely safe, how can I modify the code. Thank you.

```
#include <mutex>
#include "sqlite3.h"

class Connection
{
private:
    sqlite3* _handle;
    std::string _path;
public:
    Connection(const std::string& path) : _path(path) {
        sqlite3_open(_path.c_str(), &_handle);
        // some other initialization work..
    }
}

class Database
{
private:
    typedef enum
    {
        Void,
        Connected,
        // some other status...
    } Status;

    std::string _path;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    Status _status;
    Connection* _connection;

    void OpenDatabase()
    {
        _connection = new Connection(_path);
        _status = Connected;
    }
public:
    Connection* GetConnection()
    {
        if (_status == Connected)
            return _connection;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mutex);
        if (_status != Connected)
            OpenDatabase();
        return _connection;
    }
public:
    Database(const std::string& path) : _path(path), _status(Void) {};
};
```

Comment: Insufficient information for an authoritative answer, but looks like this is not thread safe.  It's obvious to me both that `_connection` and `_status` should only be accessed while a lock is being held on the protective mutex. However this is obviously not the case.

Comment: You're not guarding `_status`, why would you think it's safe?

Comment: I would have though OpenDatabse to return the connection instead of it operating on the class variable. Maybe what you need is a singleton? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/429476

Comment: @Tas, `_status` is modified only in `OpenDatabase`, and `OpenDatabase` is guarded by _mutex. I think that's thread-safe. But I am not sure if optimization or memory order will affect the result.

Comment: @wqyfavor I can very clearly see you accessing `_status` in `GetConnection`. Accessing the data requires it to be locked. In your question you said _If the code is not absolutely safe_ - I assure you: the code is not absolutely safe, despite what you may think.

Comment: @Tas can you provide an example of how things might go wrong given the code as shown?  I think that would be helpful as a means of demonstrating how you came to the conclusion that you did.

Comment: For efficiency, the read access of `if (_status == Connected)` in `GetConnection` is not locked. If I lock read of `_status`, the question is meaningless. So I only wonder if what I do is **safe enough**.

Answer (score 1):

> *For efficiency ... is **safe enough***

You're dealing with a database, efficiency is moot and **safe enough** is up to you

***Enough*** implies a level of allowable uncertainty. Are *you* ok with that?

What happens in that 0.001% chance it's **not** *safe enough*? Does the software crash? Does the hardware explode? Do birds turn inside out and fall from the sky?

If your `OpenDatabase` function is locked everywhere else in your `Database` class, then what's wrong with removing the first check and leaving your `GetConnection` function as so:

```
Connection* GetConnection()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mutex);
    if (_status != Connected)
        OpenDatabase();
    return _connection;
}
```

You're dealing with a database, so the few milliseconds it takes to your CPU to create and store the `std::lock_guard` and lock/unlock the `_mutex` object then preform a simple boolean check is massively insignificant compared to the 100's of milliseconds building a connection and transactional state for the database can take.

Save the birds.